# A quick way to delete a line in netBeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

I am looking for a quick way to delete a line in netBeans.

For example in vim you can just type `dd` for Deleting a line.

Comment: in netbeans you want or in some program which u r developing using netbeans...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Does Ctrl-E not work for you?  This is the default short-cut in NetBeans on a Windows machine.

If you click on Help you can get the keyboard shortcuts card, print it out, it's pretty handy and has saved me quite a bit of time hunting for easier ways to do things.

Comment: @CourtneyPattison - A yes, I didn't have a shiny machine back then - thank you for the update.

Answer (score 12):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> while your cursor on the line to be deleted.

The command will delete the line and place the cursor to the starting of next line.

Comment: `Ctrl+X` does not delete the current line but cuts it to the clipboard.

Answer (score 3):

For Mac command it is <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that Netbeans support several key bindings!

Check your key bindings first: "Tools" -> "Options" -> "Keymap". Now check the value of "Profile".

When the default key binding is active (Profile is "Netbeans"), it is `Ctrl-E` as mentioned by others. For Elipse it is `Ctrl-D`.

For all Netbeans shortcuts see: "Help" -> "Keyboard Shotcuts Card"